# VB6 calls to ActiveX component with string parameters yield weird results

Tags: string, encoding, vb6, activex

I'm currently finishing a piece of software a now gone co-worker started.

The app is coded in VB6 and uses a 3rd party ActiveX component to act upon a 3rd party system.  Our solution is basically an integration between their company's software and ours.

The issue I'm having is that there's a method call that fails consistently, even though it's passed perfectly valid parameters on our side (it's a login method).  However, when I look at the trace their application offers, I see that instead of the username I specify, it tells me (roughly) "User '⚠⚠⚠' can't login".

I figured it was likely to be an encoding issue as the ⚠ character replacing the characters I give it to log on seem to be there because the characters are unknown, but nothing I did could fix it.

Anyone know of an issue with VB6 communicating with ActiveX components like this?  Or anyone have an idea what I could try?  I'm at a loss here and if the issue is on their side, it'll be a pain to get it fixed as we don't have their source code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: (1) Please show the code (at least the place where you pass the string), (2) is this the only method with strings that fails? In other words, do you have some other call to compare its behavior?

Comment: Set objIRC = objRCL.Login("User, "pass").  It is the only one that fails, but it might be because no other calls can be made as long as I'm not logged on.

Comment: No way to tell based on the skimpy information.  Is it possible it wants Byte arrays of ANSI characters instead of Unicode Strings?

Comment: I had a problem like this some time ago when I was passing a string to a DLL written in C, to resolve it I have to convert the string to Unicode before passing it, so I am thinking that @BobRiemerma is correct.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways of passing strings. Aside from the obvious one of passing a string as in

```
DIM u As String
DIM p As String
u = "Username"
p = "Password"
Set objIRC = objRCL.Login(u, p)
```

there's also the possibility that .Login is expecting pointers to String, in which case code

```
Set objIRC = objRCL.Login(StrPtr(u), StrPtr(p))
```